# Insertion and deletion in heap sort

Tags: heapsort

This code works perfectly with some inputs. But for the input `(10 30 25 5 40 35 20)`, heap creation is correct but after deletion it's not giving sorted array. This is a code from Udemy *data structure and algorithm* course. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with this code.

```
int insert(int a[],int n)
{
    int i=n;
    int temp=a[i];
    while(i>1 && temp>a[i/2])
    {
        a[i]=a[i/2];
        i=i/2;
    }
    a[i]=temp;

}
int deletion(int a[],int n)
{ 
    int x,j,i,temp,val;
    val=a[1];
    x=a[n];
    a[n]=val;   
    a[1]=x;
    i=1;
    j=2*i;
    while(j<n-1)        

    {
        if(a[j+1]>a[j])
         j=j+1;
        if(a[i]<a[j])
          {
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=temp;
            i=j;
            j=2*i;
          } 
        else
         break;
    }


}
int main()
{
    int n,i,a[10];
    printf("enter the size of an array\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("enter the elements\n");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    insert(a,i);
    printf("inserted elements in heap are\n");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
    for(i=n;i>1;i--)
    {
        deletion(a,i);

    }
    printf("after deletion\n");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the outputs, please ?

Comment: Insertion in heap gave 40 30 35 5 10 25 20   after deletion the output was 10 5 20 25 30 35 40 .....bt it is not sorted so where is the problem ?